# Can't connect to internet

Tags: firefox

I am able to connect to my home network, but Firefox and Chrome will not connect to the internet. How can I fix this? I am using a wireless laptop. I have troubleshooted that my network is working, and I am currently using my home network with a Windows laptop I borrowed from work. Both browsers worked previously from home and the public network at the library. I am very new to Linux.

Comment: I also found a link and tried pinging. I did not receive anything when I tried to ping google.com. I put in ping 74.125.237.18 and got back PING 74.125.237.18 (74.125.237.18) 56(84) bytes of data. The link said that this means I have a DNS problem, but I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your DNS servers to `/etc/resolv.conf` file. If you don't know your DNS servers insert the following details to your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```